# Tokenizing in Xquery

Tags: xquery

How to tokenize special characters like **"&"** and **"?"** in xquery. As I'm trying to *Tokenize* these special characters, I'm unable to do this. Can u suggest me to clear this issue?

Comment: for example: "http://www.xyzasd.net/read.php?tid=68593&page=4&fpage=1"  i want "68593" from this string.so that i have to tokenize "&" from this string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to escape the ampersand as you do it in XML.

```
tokenize($string, "&amp;")
```

Alternatively, you could also use its unicode codepoint:

```
tokenize($string, codepoints-to-string(38))
```

Comment: And how can i convert this string "68593" in to an Integer?   when i'm tyrying this i'm getting error. [dynamic error [err:FORG0001]: "xs:string": invalid value for cast/constructor: can not cast to "xs:integer"]

Comment: Please ask a new question if you've got one. Have a look at [http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/), you will find that `number(68593)` is what you're looking for.