# Tokenizing a string in xquery

Tags: xquery, tokenize

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tokenizing in Xquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10641546/tokenizing-in-xquery)

Let string a = "http://ontheland.com/letus/tag/present?page=20&type=0", need to tokenize this string where i want to get "20" as integer. The main issue with this is how to tokenize "&". I have been trying with **"&"**, but no use. Can you please assist the exact problem with this.

Comment: Using "&amp;" to tokenize, but no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use &amp; as the entity for &:

```
let $a := <a><![CDATA[http://ontheland.com/letus/tag/present?page=20&type=0]]></a>
return xs:int(tokenize(tokenize($a,'&amp;')[1],'=')[last()])
```

You can try this example live at http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#H8dHNTZwa2AnbIWhKEfMQ9HKT84=

Answer (score 0):

Unless that string is CDATA, your XML is not going to be well-formed and your xquery probably won't work. If it is CDATA, you should be able to tokenize by just using `&`.

Example:

**XML**

```
<a><![CDATA[http://ontheland.com/letus/tag/present?page=20&type=0]]></a>
```

**XPath** (to be used in XQuery)

```
xs:int(tokenize(tokenize(/a,'&')[1],'=')[last()])
```

**Result**

```
20
```

---

***Tested using Saxon HE***